# C# error that Type is not referenced, but it is

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

In my project (TestProject) I reference a DLL from another project. That project uses EntityFramework.Auditing. I have a reference in TestProject to EntityFramework.Auditing and it's properties says version 1.0.0.0 but get this error:

> The type 'EntityFramework.Auditing.AuditDbContext' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'EntityFramework.Auditing, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

UPDATE:
Looked a little closer, and I'm seeing this warning:

> Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly that could not be resolved.  These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed.

I've set the output and logging to detailed, and I'm looking through it now. Not sure what I'm looking for tho.

I see this in the output:

> There was a conflict between "EntityFramework.Auditing, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a5fc4097df435221" and "EntityFramework.Auditing, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null".
>        "EntityFramework.Auditing, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a5fc4097df435221" was chosen because it was primary and "EntityFramework.Auditing, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" was not.
>        References which depend on "EntityFramework.Auditing, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a5fc4097df435221" [C:\Users\mkenyon\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\IdentityMkp\IdentityMkp\bin\EntityFramework.Auditing.dll].
>            C:\Users\mkenyon\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\IdentityMkp\IdentityMkp\bin\EntityFramework.Auditing.dll
>              Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Users\mkenyon\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\IdentityMkp\IdentityMkp\bin\EntityFramework.Auditing.dll".
>                EntityFramework.Auditing, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a5fc4097df435221, processorArchitecture=MSIL
>        References which depend on "EntityFramework.Auditing, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" [C:\Projects\BitLocker\publicationsystem\PublicationSystem.Model\bin\Debug\EntityFramework.Auditing.dll].
>            C:\Projects\BitLocker\publicationsystem\PublicationSystem.Model\bin\Debug\PublicationSystem.Model.dll
>              Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Projects\BitLocker\publicationsystem\PublicationSystem.Model\bin\Debug\PublicationSystem.Model.dll".
>                PublicationSystem.Model

Here is my .csproj file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>
    </ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{817156B0-C54C-449B-B048-876C2C01A6BB}</ProjectGuid>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>IdentityMkp</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>IdentityMkp</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <MvcBuildViews>false</MvcBuildViews>
    <UseIISExpress>true</UseIISExpress>
    <IISExpressSSLPort />
    <IISExpressAnonymousAuthentication />
    <IISExpressWindowsAuthentication />
    <IISExpressUseClassicPipelineMode />
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="EntityFramework.Auditing, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a5fc4097df435221, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>bin\EntityFramework.Auditing.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="EntityFramework.SqlServer, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\lib\net45\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="PublicationSystem.Model">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Projects\BitLocker\publicationsystem\PublicationSystem.Model\bin\Debug\PublicationSystem.Model.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.DynamicData" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Entity" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.ApplicationServices" />
    <Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Extensions" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Abstractions" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Routing" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
    <Reference Include="System.Configuration" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Services" />
    <Reference Include="System.EnterpriseServices" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <Private>True</Private>
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.1.0.0.0\lib\net40\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http">
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http.WebRequest">
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Helpers, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <Private>True</Private>
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.3.2.2\lib\net45\System.Web.Helpers.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Mvc, Version=__MvcPagesVersion__, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <Private>True</Private>
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.5.2.2\lib\net45\System.Web.Mvc.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Optimization">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.1.1.3\lib\net40\System.Web.Optimization.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <Private>True</Private>
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Razor.3.2.2\lib\net45\System.Web.Razor.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Web.WebPages, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <Private>True</Private>
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.3.2.2\lib\net45\System.Web.WebPages.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Web.WebPages.Deployment, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <Private>True</Private>
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.3.2.2\lib\net45\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <Private>True</Private>
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.3.2.2\lib\net45\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="WebGrease">
      <Private>True</Private>
      <HintPath>..\packages\WebGrease.1.5.2\lib\WebGrease.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Antlr3.Runtime">
      <Private>True</Private>
      <HintPath>..\packages\Antlr.3.4.1.9004\lib\Antlr3.Runtime.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.4\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.2.1.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.2.1.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.2.1.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Owin">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Owin.1.0\lib\net40\Owin.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Owin">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Owin.3.0.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.3.0.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Owin.Security">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Owin.Security.3.0.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.Security.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook.3.0.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.3.0.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.3.0.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google.3.0.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter.3.0.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount.3.0.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="App_Start\BundleConfig.cs" />
    <Compile Include="App_Start\FilterConfig.cs" />
    <Compile Include="App_Start\IdentityConfig.cs" />
    <Compile Include="App_Start\RouteConfig.cs" />
    <Compile Include="App_Start\Startup.Auth.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Controllers\AccountController.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Controllers\HomeController.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Controllers\ManageController.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Global.asax.cs">
      <DependentUpon>Global.asax</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Models\AccountViewModels.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Models\IdentityModels.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Models\ManageViewModels.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Startup.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Content\bootstrap.css" />
    <Content Include="Content\bootstrap.min.css" />
    <Content Include="favicon.ico" />
    <Content Include="fonts\glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg" />
    <Content Include="Global.asax" />
    <Content Include="Content\Site.css" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\bootstrap.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\bootstrap.min.js" />
    <None Include="Scripts\jquery-1.10.2.intellisense.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\jquery-1.10.2.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\jquery-1.10.2.min.js" />
    <None Include="Scripts\jquery.validate-vsdoc.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\jquery.validate.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\jquery.validate.min.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\modernizr-2.6.2.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\respond.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\respond.min.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\_references.js" />
    <Content Include="Web.config" />
    <Content Include="Web.Debug.config">
      <DependentUpon>Web.config</DependentUpon>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="Web.Release.config">
      <DependentUpon>Web.config</DependentUpon>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="Views\Web.config" />
    <Content Include="Views\_ViewStart.cshtml" />
    <Content Include="Views\Shared\Error.cshtml" />
    <Content Include="Views\Shared\_Layout.cshtml" />
    <Content Include="Views\Home\About.cshtml" />
    <Content Include="Views\Home\Contact.cshtml" />
    <Content Include="Views\Home\Index.cshtml" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\jquery-1.10.2.min.map" />
    <Content Include="Views\Account\_ExternalLoginsListPartial.cshtml" />
    <Content Include="Views\Account\ConfirmEmail.cshtml" />
    <Content Include="Views\Account\ExternalLoginConfirmation.cshtml" />
    <Content Include="Views\Account\ExternalLoginFailure.cshtml" />
    <Content Include="Views\Account\ForgotPassword.cshtml" />
    <Content Include="Views\Account\ForgotPasswordConfirmation.cshtml" />
    <Content Include="Views\Account\Login.cshtml" />
    <Content Include="Views\Account\Register.cshtml" />
    <Content Include="Views\Account\ResetPassword.cshtml" />
    <Content Include="Views\Account\ResetPasswordConfirmation.cshtml" />
    <Content Include="Views\Account\SendCode.cshtml" />
    <Content Include="Views\Account\VerifyCode.cshtml" />
    <Content Include="Views\Manage\AddPhoneNumber.cshtml" />
    <Content Include="Views\Manage\ChangePassword.cshtml" />
    <Content Include="Views\Manage\Index.cshtml" />
    <Content Include="Views\Manage\ManageLogins.cshtml" />
    <Content Include="Views\Manage\SetPassword.cshtml" />
    <Content Include="Views\Manage\VerifyPhoneNumber.cshtml" />
    <Content Include="Views\Shared\Lockout.cshtml" />
    <Content Include="Views\Shared\_LoginPartial.cshtml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="App_Data\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="fonts\glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff" />
    <Content Include="fonts\glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf" />
    <Content Include="fonts\glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot" />
    <Content Include="packages.config" />
    <None Include="Project_Readme.html" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">10.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="false" />
  <Target Name="MvcBuildViews" AfterTargets="AfterBuild" Condition="'$(MvcBuildViews)'=='true'">
    <AspNetCompiler VirtualPath="temp" PhysicalPath="$(WebProjectOutputDir)" />
  </Target>
  <ProjectExtensions>
    <VisualStudio>
      <FlavorProperties GUID="{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21}">
        <WebProjectProperties>
          <UseIIS>True</UseIIS>
          <AutoAssignPort>True</AutoAssignPort>
          <DevelopmentServerPort>15041</DevelopmentServerPort>
          <DevelopmentServerVPath>/</DevelopmentServerVPath>
          <IISUrl>http://localhost:12454/</IISUrl>
          <NTLMAuthentication>False</NTLMAuthentication>
          <UseCustomServer>False</UseCustomServer>
          <CustomServerUrl>
          </CustomServerUrl>
          <SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>False</SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>
        </WebProjectProperties>
      </FlavorProperties>
    </VisualStudio>
  </ProjectExtensions>
  <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it.
       Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
  </Target> -->
</Project>
```

Here's my web.config:

```
  <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
<!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 --></configSections>
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-IdentityMkp-20151021040959.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-IdentityMkp-20151021040959;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  <add name="MkpContext" connectionString="Data Source=192.168.1.16;Initial Catalog=Mkp;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=xxxxxxxx; MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Min Pool Size=20; Max Pool Size=200;Pooling=true;Connection Timeout=30" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
<appSettings>
  <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
  <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
  <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="None" />
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
  <modules>
    <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.2.0" newVersion="5.2.2.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
<entityFramework>
  <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  <providers>
    <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
  </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

Comment: You have to add that EF assembly to the test project, don't forget the connection string in other project app.config for EF...

Comment: you might be referencing a local copy rather than the one in the GAC or something. try removing and re-adding the reference. make sure to go through the .NET list rather than browsing for a .dll file. check to see if there is more than one of them in the list as well, and make sure to try them separately if there is. note that if you have resharper, it will usually do this for you automatically with a quickfix.

Comment: I've added the assembly to both projects, and added the connection string. Still no good. I've removed the reference and re-added, still no good. Not sure how to fix it with resharper, but I do have resharper. I added this with NuGet.

Comment: You might need to explore app.config bindingRedirects. It sounds like something has a reference to an older or a newer version of this library and that's getting loaded first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a stupid user mistake.

The EntityFramework.Auditing.AuditDbContext assembly is a NuGet package, but it can also be downloaded as source code. I'm using assemblies from another solution, and failed to remember that we had the source code as a project in that solution.

I needed to point to the assembly we built in our other solution so that the Models assembly I was using would understand the Auditing assembly.